# Accessing network path using C# from Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

We have developed an application in C#. Net to connect Windows network path and check one directory availability. When we are running the application from **Windows OS**, its working fine. But when running it on **Ubuntu 16.04 OS**, it is not recognizing the Windows network directory.

We tried the code as follows but not succeeded,

```
Directory.Exists("\\\\xxx.xxx.x.xx\\DirectoryName")

Directory.Exists(@"\\xxx.xxx.x.xx\DirectoryName")

Directory.Exists("smb://xxx.xxx.x.xx/DirectoryName")
```

Please suggest that how can we modify the C# code to run it from Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Write a logic to check OS in .net code. If it is windows use windows path and for Linux use Linux specific file path.

Comment: @prisar, Thanks. For Linux, how the above mentioned path needs to changed? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can set-up the environment on the machine before running, you could try mounting the network path and then use that.

To mount the SMB share - the instructions [from the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) are pretty comprehensive.

e.g.

```
mkdir ~/localMountPoint
mount -t cifs /xxx.xxx.x.xx/DirectoryName ~/localMountPoint -ou ser=myname,pass=mypassword
```

You can then just use:

```
Directory.Exists("~/localMountPoint/DirectoryName")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try this solution and come back ASAP.