# how to get the files from a network path in c# netcore running in linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I have this c# netcore5 code:

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("\\servername\foldername");
```

which works fine when I run in windows, but it doesn't when I run it in linux.
I changed the path to "//servername/foldername" but it still complains. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Linux, but if I'm not mistaken, in Windows works because it auto-mounts network paths when you access them, but in Linux you have to mount them manually (for instance,  `mount -t cifs my-network-location mount-path`).

Comment: [Accessing network path using C# from Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52081068/205233)