# Why .NET Core on Docker Add '/app/' in Path?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I am having trouble console app with **.NET Core** in **Docker**. Actually, I can running without Docker. But, I can't with Docker Container. When I access file in other server, application add ***'/app/'*** server path.

```
string pathXml = @"\\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\X.xml";
using (var fileStream = File.OpenText(pathXml))
{..}
```

When use File.OpenText, pathXml return ***"/app/\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\X.xml"***. It's trying to reach that address. But can't find it because there is no equivalent. Why adding *'/app/'* in path? Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: Do you mean it tries to open the file `/app/\\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\X.xml`? `pathXml` itself is unlikely to change to something else.

Comment: Yes, it's trying to reach that address. But can't find it because there is no equivalent.

Comment: Maybe somewhere in the docker docs they added that convention such as a work directory. Other than that, I don't see any reason why they would implement it this way. Docker containers are meant to be isolated so why even bother accessing something on the outside? Check out [How to access files outside the Docker container](https://www.tech-wiki.online/en/docker-access-files-outside-container.html)

Comment: It seems like you are running a Linux image in your docker container. You can't just access SMB-resources that way on Linux afaik, you will need to mount it and use the mount path to access the files instead.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, You are right, I am running a Linux image in your docker container. When I use "pathXml = pathXml .Replace('\\', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);" command, this return "/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/X.xml". But it will be "\\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\X.xml"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing network path using C# from Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081068/accessing-network-path-using-c-sharp-from-ubuntu)

Comment: The problem isn't just the slashes, accessing any SMB-share via `\\ip\share\file.ext` is enabled by default in Windows but it isn't on Linux. You need to mount it first. Check the link from Hans Kilian for an example.

Comment: Thanks for attention. When I used "SMBLibrary", I can access file Linux and Windows docker container.